multiple association classes on the same relation
I want to add multiple association classes on the same relation, to manage absence and group affection between a student and course, I read that an association class is a description of a relation, so to not be in conflict with this definition I draw 2 relations between my classes, and for each relation there is a corresponding association class.
here is my current UML diagram:

the diagram with multiple association classes on the same relation:

so which on is following UML standards.
both diagram I believe will be translated into the same relation database scheme, so I just don't know which one is actually following the UML standards.

The association class in UML is at the same time an association and a class. The consequence is that it is the same thing with a unique name:

The first diagram is correct: two different association classes between the same classes are legit, and correspond to two different semantic relationships (absences and belongingness are two different concerns).

The second diagram is not valid UML, since the two association classes cannot and do not share the same name.


